# How to disable one of 2 input with same names

Tags: html, input, send

I have 2 *selects* with same names. One is displayed, and the other is hidden.

```
<select name="city" style="display: none;">
    <option value="notSend">foo</option>
</select>

<select name="city">
    <option value="send">foo</option>
</select>
```

How can I send **only** select, which are displayed?

Comment: Disable the one which is hidden

Comment: why would you do this? Surely a radio button would better suit your needs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use HTML **disabled** attribute to disable `<select>` and hide that element using Jquery **hide** method

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/zZTMd/

**Note:** Don't forget to include JQuery library file

Answer (score 0):

Disable the code which should not be send.

Disable the HTML like this without removing the code:

```
 <!--select name="city" style="display: none;">
 <option value="notSend">foo</option>
 </select-->

 <select name="city">
 <option value="send">foo</option>
 </select>
```